# Changing the look and feel of the SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API dialog

Tags: android, recaptcha

I wonder if anyone knows how to change the look and feel of the dialog that is displayed by the [SafetyNet reCAPTCHA API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha).

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image: reCAPTCHA dialog]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, we ended up using it without changing the look and feel.